# Derivative of $\log \frac{x^3}{5}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Okay, so I'm starting to learn about the properties of derivatives and I was told to find the derivative of the title. At first, I tried to solve it ​by doing the following:

$$ \begin{align}f'(x) &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log \frac {x^3}{5} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (\log x^3-\log5)  \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log x^3-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \log 5 \\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{x^3\ln10}-0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Since} \  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log_a x=\frac{1}{x\ln a}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{x^3\ln10} 
\end{align}
$$

Then I realized that I can "take the exponent out" of the logarithm and the derivative to get a different result:

$$ \begin{align} f'(x)&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log x^3-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \log 5 \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (3 \log x)-0 \\[4pt]
&= 3 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \log x \\[4pt]
&= \frac{3}{x \ln 10} 
\end{align}$$

What is happening here? Am I correctly using the properties? If so, why do I get different results?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \log[f(x)] = \frac{1}{f(x)} \times f'(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the chain rule for derivatives. For instance:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log x^3 \neq \frac{1}{x^3 \ln(10)} $$

The correct answer is

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log x^3= \frac{1}{x^3 \ln(10)} \cdot  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^3 = \frac{1}{x^3 \ln(10)} \cdot 3x^2 =\frac{3}{x\ln(10)} \cdot $$

Comment: Is that to say that I can't apply my already known derivative ($\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log_ax=\frac{1}{x \ln a}$) if $x$ is raised to a power? Why is the chain rule a mandatory step?

Comment: @Ciro: The Chain Rule is needed whenever you have a composition. This is a composition. You need it because otherwise the computation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You did a very critical mistake...

Why $\frac d{dx}\log_{10} x^3=\frac1{x^3\log10}$? $\frac d{dx}\log x^3=\frac{\frac d{dx}x^3}{x^3\log10}=\frac{3x^2}{x^3\log10}=\frac3{x\log10}$.